# SQL Server use extended character range for "SELECT WHERE IN" query

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I need to be able to use the extended character range in an "IN" clause.

I can use the N character in a "LIKE" clause to to an extended character search but can't apply the same to the "IN" clause.

I can use N in the following query to pull back all rows with the extended character range:

```
select ... from CUSTOMER where NAME like N'周';
```

I need to expand this query to be able to choose from a list of items **with the extended character range**:

```
select ... from CUSTOMER where NAME in ('周','年');
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `N` on those string literals inside the `IN` in exactly the same way as you do in the first code sample? `N` is part of the literal syntax.

Comment: Use a table variable and join to it, or just add the `N` to the literals. BTW your `LIKE` is equivalent to `=` here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you,  I was escaping them incorrectly, I now have select ... from CUSTOMER where NAME in (N'周',N'年'); and is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

N '... is used for Unicode, since not always in the databases it is configured to be used with multilanguage. try putting N 'inside all your inclusion sentences.

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE NAME IN (N'周',N'年');
```